# Animating some text on slider using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Hello I am using the soliloquy slider plug in for wordpress, I am trying to get it to animate some text on each slide. Here is the little jquery function I wrote that seems like it should work.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // var $ulist = document.getElementById("soliloquy-325")
    var $allElements =  $("#soliloquy-325").find("li");
    if($allElements.hasClass("soliloquy-active-slide")){
    $this.find("soliloquy-caption").html("<div class='caption'><p>hello</p>            </div>").fadeIn("slow");
    }
    });
```

But it doesn't seem to do anything and I'm not getting any errors when I check my console. Any Help would be greatly appreciated.`

Comment: please provide slide HTML that is in the li as well.

Answer (score 2):

I put something in jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/donlaur/SA3La/
It does a little animation, not much.  You can change effects or even use .animate if you wanted to do something different.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
// var ulist = document.getElementById("soliloquy-325")
var allElements = $("#soliloquy-325").find("li");
if (allElements.hasClass("soliloquy-active-slide")) {
    $(".soliloquy-caption").html("<div class='caption'><p>hello</p></div>");
    // You set the new hello to a class of caption now
    $(".caption").fadeOut("1000").fadeIn("1500");
}
});
```